# Vue component prop `undefined` when called from watcher callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been writing a Vue client for an instructor API for an e-learning site that fetches the associated Q&A threads for each course taught by that instructor.

The client first populates a list of courses.

Next, when a course is clicked, the ID for that course is passed to a child component as a prop called `courseid`, so the child component can then itself perform an API lookup to get the threads for that course using that ID.

The child component contains a method that performs the API request to get the Q&A threads called `getThreads`, using the prop `courseid` as a parameter in that request.

Finally, a watcher watches the prop `courseid` and calls `getThreads` if it changes. At least, it should.

When I click a course in the parent component's course list, the ID of that course is successfully passed to the child component as the prop `courseid` (the `courseid` prop is shown with the correct value in the Vue DevTools panel), but the browser console displays the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "courseid": "ReferenceError: courseid is not defined"
```

Here is the content of the `<script>` section of the aforementioned child element:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'qAndAThread',
  data() {
    return {
      axiosResult: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  props: {
    courseid:{
      default: '',
      type: String
    },
  watch: { 
    courseid: function () {
      this.getThreads();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getThreads: function makeRequest() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const token = '*redacted*';
      const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: '*redacted*',
        timeout: 100000,
        headers: {
          Accept: '*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      instance
        .get(`/courses/${courseid}/questions/?page_size=200`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.axiosResult = response.data;
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.unread = this.axiosResult.count;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          //console.log(error);
          this.axiosResult = error;
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Any assistance offered will be gratefully received!

Comment: In your `.get` call, `${courseid}` should be `${this.courseid}`

Comment: Many thanks! You were not mistaken. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.get(`/courses/${courseid}/questions/?page_size=200`)
```

should be

```
.get(`/courses/${this.courseid}/questions/?page_size=200`)
```

`courseid` is on your object so leaving off `this` will make it `undefined`. If you do `this.courseid` it should work.

I'm not up to date with how `vue` maintains scope, but you may also need to do this:

```
watch: { 
    courseid: function () {
      this.getThreads();
    },
  },
```

might need to be

```
watch: { 
    courseid: function () {
      this.getThreads.bind(this);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Holy moly. What a rookie error on my part! You're absolutely right, thank you. The second change you suggested (adding .bind(this)) wasn't required FYI. StackOverflow won't let me click the accept button for another minute, apparently, but rest assured, I will just as soon as StackOverflow permits.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure if you needed that part. I know that always gets me everytime when working with callbacks. Glad things are working.

Comment: I'm still getting my head around it. Whenever I think I've sussed it, Vue punishes me for my hubris. You live and learn. Thanks again!